# What is wrong with this simple XSL Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I am learning XSLT and trying out a very simple example. Here is what I tried -

The source XML file which I want to transform -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="reverse.xslt"?>
<Configuration>
  <MyConfiguration>
    <Value>
    </Value>
  </MyConfiguration>
</Configuration>
```

The transformation in the `reverse.xslt` file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <testNode>
       abc
    </testNode>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I open the source file in IE7 I am expecting the output to be -

```
<testNode>
  abc
</testNode>
```

However what I get is

`abc`

Where is it going wrong?

**Edit:** Both source and the transformation file are in the same folder.

Comment: What happens if you open the transformation output with notepad?

Comment: In the notepad? I just have the source file and the transformation and I open the source in IE7 or Firefox and am expecting to see output as described above. How can I view the output in notepad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your xslt is absolutely correct and is also producing the output you expact. But HTML-Browsers are made to display HTML code. So your expected output `<testNode>  abc  </testNode>` will also be interpreated as HTML an so only the text will be shown, as `testNode` is not a valid HTML-Tag.

If you open your file with Firefox and inspect it with [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) you will see what you expected.